# Node.js - Configuring $NODE_PATH with NVM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nvm

On my way setting up `Node.js` with `NVM`, I stumbled upon an error when using `Yeoman`. I got 
the error

```
Cannot find module 'yeoman-generator'
```

After some research I found [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594541/npm-global-install-cannot-find-module), which is also about my problem. Now I tried to do so, but the problem I have is, that I want to use different versions of Node.js over the system with the use of NVM. Now is it possible to change the $NODE_PATH dynamically, if the Node.js version changes with the help of NVM? Because my $NODE_PATH is empty at the moment (this is causing the problem).

```
$ which node
/Users/dschmidt/.nvm/v0.10.35/bin/node
$ which npm
/Users/dschmidt/.nvm/v0.10.35/bin/npm
$ echo $NODE_PATH
[empty]
```

Would be glad about every answer I get about this. I searched the web for this, but could not find one post about this specifically.

Comment: `$ export NODE_PATH=whatever`

Comment: I know this, I mentioned **dynamically**.

Comment: Also looking for what others did. Did you find a solution @DominikSchmidt?

Comment: I fixed it by just installing Node without NVM. But didn't find a solution for this with the use of NVM.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/586) help?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Adding following to `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` helps

```
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:`npm root -g`
```

I am not expert whether that is good.

[source](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/586#issuecomment-68220064) as pointed out by Pensierinmusica

Comment: This is the correct answer specifically for the question asked in regards to working with yeoman generators.

Comment: Better to use double-quotes around the value, `export NODE_PATH="..."`. If there are spaces anywhere in the paths, double-quotes will save the day.

Comment: in my setup, I am happily using node via nvm in one shell, and `npm root -g` produces the correct path. But when I open another shell, `npm root -g` shows that npm is not found.

Comment: also, will this actually be dynamic? or just on shell load?

Answer (score 41):

NVM will set the path for node and npm once you run

```
nvm use <node_version>
```

However, that is just for the current shell and any new shells will not have a version of node an npm selected until your run the previous command  unless you set a default version

```
nvm alias default <node_version>
```

voila! You have a working version of npm and node in any new shell you open.

To change the default simply run it again with the new version of node you want to use. e.g.

```
nvm alias default v5.4.0
```

Comment: I had to drop the backtick marks `  ` for this to work for me. Heads up for other noobs. nvm alias default x.x.x   I'm on Linux Mint 18.1 Serena using nvm.

Comment: Your answer is about general nvm usage. The original query is regarding setting the NODE_PATH variable as per nvm node version (dynamically being the keyword here)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing the trick. `echo $NODE_PATH` is blank for me after setting this up.

Comment: This in fact doesn't answer the question ...nvm alias .. sets the node/npm version that will be available as a command, but it's not setting the $NODE_PATH variable, which is needed by some applications to work correctly :/

Comment: @funder7 you need to set the $NODE_PATH variable in your .bash_profile or .zshrc or .bashrc as part the installation of nvm

Comment: Well I don't think that it's a manual operation, the point of nvm is having node/npm version swapped on your behalf. Nvm installs a nvm.sh script into your shell configuration file, that will handle everything..Too much time has passed so I don't remember now, but reading my comment in the next answer, probably I've solved with `nvm alias default <version>`. Cheers

Comment: For me, I had a package whose binary was in: `~/.nvm/versions/node/vx.x.x/lib/node_modules/node_modules/my_package`, so I had to add it to the `PATH` explicitly because it wasn't under the default `~/.nvm/versions/node/vx.x.x/bin`, which is what gets automatically added by NVM. I added it to the `PATH` like so: `export PATH="$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/vx.x.x/lib/node_modules/node_modules/my_package:$PATH"`

Comment: This is no longer working on Windows 11.  This answer needs to be updated by someone who knows what they are doing.

Comment: I run `nvm install stable --lts && nvm alias default stable` but the selected node version changes every new terminal session

Answer (score 24):

I figured a way to make this work.

In your `~/.bash_rc` file or `~/.zsh_rc` add this line:

```
export NODE_PATH=`which node`
```

Open new shell or run this `source ~/.bash_rc` to pick up the changes

Comment: `which node` in zshrc seems to reference system Node. `which $NODE_PATH ` which spits out `/usr/local/bin/node`. Then `/usr/local/bin/node -v` is system Node for me

Comment: have you set the version to be used with nvm alias default <version> ?

Comment: in my setup, I have nvm setting the node version in one shell, but when I open another, `which node` returns blank.

Answer (score 2):

This (taken from GN. and Nick) works fine for me, but I needed to add it to `~/.bash_profile` because I use Bash as a shell on my Mac

```
export NODE_PATH=`which node`
```

Comment: no ``which node`` points to executable
but  ``npm root -g`` point to the path of node_modules