# VsCode different behavior between run-mode and debug-mode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ping

when I run the following python code in run mode, the response equals 0, when I run it in debug mode, the response is 127 and the failure `/bin/sh: ping: command not found` occured.

`cmd = '-c 1'`
`host = 192.168.1.1`
`response = subprocess.call(f'ping {cmd} {host}, shell=True')`

my launch.json looks like that:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

When using `response = os.system(f'ping {cmd} {host}')`, the response in run mode is 0 and in debug mode the response is 32512 and the failure `sh: ping: command not found` occured.

Can someone help me?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61686267/5783608) help?

Comment: How should I change the settings.json?

{
    "python.pythonPath": ".venv/bin/python"
}

Comment: I tried "terminal.integrated.automationShell.linux": "-i" and "terminal.integrated.automationShell.linux": "-l" but same issue.